# Postgresql In Nestjs Cannot use variable time

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time, nestjs

**Syntax Error Near ":"**

```
SELECT jr.id as join_room_id,c.id as customer_id,
       CONCAT(c.firstname,' ',c.lastname) as customer_name,
       jr.join_date,
       jr.time_in,
       jr.time_out
FROM join_rooms jr
INNER JOIN customer c on c.id = jr.customer_id
WHERE (
    time_in BETWEEN '09:00' AND '9:59' OR
    time_out BETWEEN '9:00'::time AND '9:59' OR
    '9:00' BETWEEN time_in AND time_out OR
    '9:59' BETWEEN  time_in AND time_out
          ) AND join_date='2021-02-18' AND  room_id=2
```

above code work normal

```
findIsRoomExist({
    time_in,
    time_out,
    join_date,
    room_id,
  }: UpdateJoinRoomDto) {
    return from(
      this.joinRoomRepo.query(`
      SELECT jr.id as join_room_id,c.id as customer_id,
      CONCAT(c.firstname,' ',c.lastname) as customer_name,
      jr.join_date,
      jr.time_in,
      jr.time_out
FROM join_rooms jr
INNER JOIN customer c on c.id = jr.customer_id
WHERE (
   time_in BETWEEN ${time_in} AND  ${time_out} OR
   time_out BETWEEN  ${time_in} AND  ${time_out} OR
   '09:00' BETWEEN time_in AND time_out OR
   '09:59' BETWEEN  time_in AND time_out
         ) AND join_date='2021-02-18' AND  room_id=${2};
`),
}
```

code above is an error when I try to use a string template in this function
**
time_int type is time
time_out type is time

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.1 with Nestjs as a backend

when I query in DataGrip it's work well but I use it in NestJS query then it got error like :
**

```
[Nest] 14421   - 02/18/2021, 5:07:34 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] syntax error at or near ":" +218799ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near ":"
    at new QueryFailedError (/Users/rom/Documents/pos-gym-api/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/Users/rom/Documents/pos-gym-api/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:247:31)
    at step (/Users/rom/Documents/pos-gym-api/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.throw (/Users/rom/Documents/pos-gym-api/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at rejected (/Users/rom/Documents/pos-gym-api/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Anyone can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but is it possible that ${time_in} AND  ${time_out} are passed as timestamp (date+time as defined by graphql) rather than time.  Casting the parameters as time in the wuery would then solve your problem.  cast(${time_in} as time) for example.

Comment: it's doesn't work it's still show **syntax error at or near ":" ** like this

Comment: Could you add the generated query ? Also, why are you using the plain query feature ? You can be exposed to a Sql Injection

Comment: @JuanRambal how to prevent injection sir ?

Comment: Use the query builder, you can access that with .createQueryBuilder method. More info here: https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder